# Qt headers not indexed with Eclipse because of -isystem

Tags: eclipse, qt, header-files

I have a qmake project which I develop with Eclipse (Kepler). The problem is, that the indexer does not seem to recognize included header files for Qt when the path to the includes is specified by the -isystem directive. This directive is used in the generated Makefile:

```
INCPATH       = -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtSvg -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtPrintSupport -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++
```

If I change -isystem to -I by hand then everything compiles ok and now all Qt symbols are found and properly indexed (no Qt methods flagged red anymore, tooltips working etc.).

Of course I wrote the relevant Qt include directories in the window 'Properties|C C++ general|Paths and symbols', but doing this alone does not help as long as -isystem instead of -I is used to specify the include paths.

How can I get the indexer working properly without having to change manually the -isystem to -I ?